# this.property is undefined: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Tags: javascript, class, oop, this, undefined

I'm making something to **visualize photographs**.
The goal is to select the picture you want in the "list" to make it appear on the main HTML element. But to help you find where you are in the list there's a class putting borders on the element you selected.

**The issue :**
The function executing with the event `this.block.onclick = function ()` begins well, the `.selected` is removed from the initial selected element, but when comes `this.block.classList.add('selected');` I get this error:

> media_visu.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

I tried to put the `function` outside, tried `className`, `setAttribute`, but nothing changed: my `this.block` seems to be `undefined`.

**mediavisu.js :**

```
var mediaVisu = function () {
    'use strict';

    window.console.log('mediaVisu loaded');




    var i,
    visu = document.querySelector("#img"),
    Album = [];

    function Photo(nb, folder) {
        this.block = document.querySelector("#list_img_" + nb);
        this.place = 'url(../src/' + folder + '/' + nb + '.jpg)';
        this.block.onclick = function () {
            for (i = 0; i < Album.length; i += 1) {
                window.console.log(Album[i].block);
                if (Album[i].block.classList.contains('selected')) {
                    Album[i].block.classList.remove('selected');
                }
            }
            visu.style.background = this.place;
            window.console.log(visu.style.background);
            window.console.log(this.place);
            this.block.classList.add('selected');
        };
        Album[Album.length] = this;
    }

    var test_a = new Photo(1, "test"),
    test_b = new Photo(2, "test"),
    test_c = new Photo(3, "test"),
    test_d = new Photo(4, "test"),
    test_e = new Photo(5, "test");

    window.console.log(Album);
    for (i = 0; i < Album.length; i += 1) {
        window.console.log(Album[i]);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the onclick function, `this` will be the element that was clicked

so you can simply use

```
this.classList.add('selected');
```

you may need to rethink using `this.place` as `this` wont be the `this` you think it is .. a common solution is as follows

```
function Photo(nb, folder) {
    this.block = document.querySelector("#list_img_" + nb);
    this.place = 'url(../src/' + folder + '/' + nb + '.jpg)';
    var self = this;
    this.block.onclick = function () {
        for (i = 0; i < Album.length; i += 1) {
            window.console.log(Album[i].block);
            if (Album[i].block.classList.contains('selected')) {
                Album[i].block.classList.remove('selected');
            }
        }
        visu.style.background = self.place;
        window.console.log(visu.style.background);
        window.console.log(self.place);
        this.classList.add('selected');
    };
    Album[Album.length] = this;
}
```

alternatively, using bind

```
function Photo(nb, folder) {
    this.block = document.querySelector("#list_img_" + nb);
    this.place = 'url(../src/' + folder + '/' + nb + '.jpg)';
    this.block.onclick = function () {
        for (i = 0; i < Album.length; i += 1) {
            window.console.log(Album[i].block);
            if (Album[i].block.classList.contains('selected')) {
                Album[i].block.classList.remove('selected');
            }
        }
        visu.style.background = this.place;
        window.console.log(visu.style.background);
        window.console.log(this.place);
        this.block.classList.add('selected');
    }.bind(this);
    Album[Album.length] = this;
}
```

note: now you go back to `this.block.classList.add('selected')` as `this` is now the `this` you were expecting before

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now ! :)
I'll be more careful.

Comment: Glad to help, @AymericMayeux - but someone else obviously doesn't like the code that works! whoever downvoted, please help me make the answer more betterer, let me know why a correct and working answer is not useful

Comment: I saw the downvote. I can't up because I'm too new there. But your answer stay correct !

Comment: I don't care about votes, except downvotes with no explanation - anonymous cowards

Answer (score 0):

You can access to it with 'this' (as mentionned in the previous answer) or with the event target :

```
    this.block.onclick = function (e) {
        for (i = 0; i < Album.length; i += 1) {
            window.console.log(Album[i].block);
            if (Album[i].block.classList.contains('selected')) {
                Album[i].block.classList.remove('selected');
            }
        }
        visu.style.background = this.place;
        window.console.log(visu.style.background);
        window.console.log(this.place);
        e.target.classList.add('selected');
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, I've made the edit for "this.place", but why do you think the e.target is unreliable ?

Comment: you totally messed the code now ... e.target instead of this.place? not even close

Comment: Just not concentrated at all, sorry. I will remove this answer since your answer do the job, it will be clearer.

Comment: no, yours is a perfectly good alternative (maybe a better one) - my comment about e.target being unreliable is not something I can qualify - I'll remove that comment